# How to make a NSImageCell editable so that I can click on it and perform some operation?

Tags: macos, cocoa

The method

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

is not called when I click on a NSImageCell, I guess because it is not a NSActionCell. Is there a way to make it to invoke the method anyway?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You cannot edit the NSImageCell as it is non editable . So the delegate method `- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex`will never get called. If you want some other method which should get called when click on NSImageCell then use this `- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldTrackCell:(NSCell *)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row

Comment: The problem with the method you suggest tableView:shouldSelectRow is that it is invoked only if the row is not already selected.

Comment: I have modified the delegate method on the basis of your requirement  please follow above code.

Comment: Use this - (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldTrackCell:(NSCell *)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row also i have updated the same on above code